# Next Auth - the signIn function always returns a status of 200

Tags: javascript, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I am creating my own login page in Next Auth and I have encountered a problem. After submitting the form, I check if the data is correct. If it is, I send JWT and redirect to `/dashboard` - it works as I would like. However, if the login data is incorrect I would like to return an error to my login page. However, when I return `return null`, the response status is 200, as if there is no error. Only the error property changes.

Currently, I base the return on the `error` and display the error based on it:

Login page:

```js
const Login = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState();

    const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const login = e.target[0].value;
        const password = e.target[1].value;

        if (login.length && password.length) {
            const res = await signIn("credentials", {
                login,
                password,
                redirect: false,
            });
            if (res.error) setLoginError(true);
            if (!res.error) router.push("/dashboard");
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className={styles.login}>
                <form onSubmit={handleLogin} className={styles.form}>
                    <h2 className={styles.header}>Login</h2>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Login"
                        className={styles.input}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Hasło"
                        className={styles.input}
                    />
                    <button className={styles.button}>Log in</button>
                </form>
                {loginError && <div>ERROR</div>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

Route:

```js
export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: "credentials",
            type: "credentials",

            credentials: {
                login: {
                    label: "login",
                    type: "text",
                },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                try {
                    await connect();
                    const user = await User.findOne({
                        login: credentials.login,
                    });
                    if (!user) return null;

                    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(
                        credentials?.password,
                        user?.password
                    );

                    if (isPasswordValid) {
                        const { password, _id: id, ...userRest } = user?._doc;
                        const userWithoutPassword = { id, ...userRest };

                        const accessToken = signJwtAccessToken({
                            userWithoutPassword,
                        });

                        return { ...userWithoutPassword, accessToken };
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    return new NextResponse("Database Error", { status: 500 });
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            return { ...token, ...user };
        },

        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.user = token;
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
            return session;
        },
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login",
    },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

However, is this a good approach? Is it possible to return `{status: 401, ok: false}`?

Answer (score 1):

It is a [bug](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7725) in NextAuth but there is a [workaround](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7638#issuecomment-1599319687).

Answer (score 0):

You are returning null in case the data is invalid. `null !== Error`. You need to throw error if the data is invalid.

Something like this:

```
try {
    await connect();
    const user = await User.findOne({
        login: credentials.login,
    });
    if (!user) throw new Error('Invalid credentials');

    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(
        credentials?.password,
        user?.password
    );

    if (isPasswordValid) {
        const { password, _id: id, ...userRest } = user?._doc;
        const userWithoutPassword = { id, ...userRest };

        const accessToken = signJwtAccessToken({
            userWithoutPassword,
        });

        return { ...userWithoutPassword, accessToken };
    } else {
        throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
    }
} catch (error) {
    return new NextResponse("Database Error", { status: 500 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new folder `patches` in the root directory of my application (at the `node_modules` level), in which I added a file named `next-auth+4.22.1.patch`, into which I pasted the code given in the workaround. However, when I run `npx patch-package next-auth`, I get a response:

> PS C:\Users\iktor\Desktop\system> npx patch-package next-auth
> patch-package 7.0.0
> Creating temporary folder
> Installing next-auth@4.22.1 with npm
> Diffing your files with clean files
> ⁉️  Not creating patch file for package 'next-auth'
> ⁉️  There don't appear to be any changes.

And the file `/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js` has not been updated.
I have the next-auth ^4.22.1 version installed

Comment: You do not need to run `npx patch-package next-auth` as this command is supposed to create a new patch file based on your local changes. To apply the existing patch: 1) Add the patch file to the `patches` folder; 2) Add `"postinstall": "patch-package"` script to your `package.json`; 3) Run `npm install` | Detailed instructions - https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package